# Do we need to add interface Runnable in our UML class diagram?

Tags: java, sockets, uml, runnable, class-diagram

I have created a simple FlappyBird clone game with socket programming and now I am doing the UML diagram.
My classes implements Runnable

Like:

```
static class Flappy implements Runnable{....}
```

and:

```
public class Client extends Application implements Runnable{.....}
```

[image: Here what i have tried]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UML is methodology agnostic. So, it all depends on the **purpose** of your [class diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html):

- If it is an analysis or a **domain model**, the `Runnable` is not relevant (as the other answer rightly pointed out)
- If it is a **design model**, i.e. a model that explains how your solution works, it depends how relevant `Runnable` is for your design:

  - if nothing in your solution requires a `Runnable`, you don’t need to show it.
  - if one class expects to use a `Runnable` or if the class is expected to provide this interface in the larger view of the [component design](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html), then you should show it.
- If it is an **implementation model**, i.e a model that aims to document precisely how your solution is implemented, the `Runnable` should be documented. Be aware that the use of such detailed implementation models is good for school-work but is not an interesting option for real world projects because it’s difficult to maintain and somewhat redundant with the code, unless you have reverse-engineering tools that can generate the diagram for you.

If you decide to show the relation, you’ll have to rework your graphical layout:

- the arrow head must be replaced with the blank triangle of [generalization](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html?context=class-diagrams). A plain arrow head is ambiguous and could mislead the reader to think that it’s a [navigable association](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#navigability) (in principle shown with an open arrow head, but an arrow head nevertheless)
- but since [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) is an interface, and your classes `implement` it and do not `extend` it, you should use a dashed line to show that it’s the [realization](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html?context=class-diagrams) of an [interface](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/interface.html) (which is a dependency, with a slightly different meaning that the inheritance/generalization).

Comment: Best answer, while the currently accepted one is the 'worst' because too restrictive

Comment: @bruno Thanks for the appreciation! You made my day :-) I tried indeed to give a more complete view  so that OP can objectively decide what’s best in view of the intent.

Answer (score 3):

Though the (formerly) accepted answer by user7 is right per se, there's also a "it depends". If you create your UML for a machine (a code generator) or a coding monkey you will have to add it in order to make it complete. If it's for a common (human) understanding you can omit those details.

As a side note: your arrows are wrong. Those are extensions (used only in profile definitions), not realizations. A realization has an open triangle and a dashed line.

Comment: Was just writing an answer but it took me obviously at least 22 minutes to write on my tiny smartphone, before I read yours ;-)

Comment: @Christophe Your's as always the most complete (and best) :-)

Comment: Thank you very much :-) Yours has the advantage of being very concise. ;-)